# How to set Role dependencies in Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, failover

I have a 2 node cluster with 5 configured roles (Generic Service). The services need to run on a single machine (one is a database, one is a server,...)

I want to configure the cluster so that if a single role fails and is moved to another machine that the other roles are moved to the that machine too.

I tried to configure this without avail. If I open the Dependencies tab in the Properties windows of a Role there is only the IP Address resource available.

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I created a role for every service, which wasn't OK. I should have created a single "Other Server" role, right click on it and add resources to that role.